# callback function of this menu button in javascript

Tags: javascript

It's defined here

```
var CMenu = cc.Sprite.extend({

onClickCallback: null,

onClick: function (callback) {
    this.onClickCallback = callback;
},
handleTouches: function (touch, evt) {
    (this.hovered && this.onClickCallback) && this.onClickCallback();});
```

It's being called here

```
backMenu.onClick(function () {
    window.location.href = "http://www.test.com";
});
```

is `this.onClickCallback = this.onClickCallback()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.onClickCallback` simply refers to the property `onClickCallback` of the `this` object. This will give you the function itself. On the other hand `this.onClickCallback()` *executes* that property considering it as a function and will return its result.

So `this.onClickCallback` is not the same as `this.onClickCallback()`